Rebuild an existing project for the first time in Android Studio
I have opened an existing Java/Android project in Android Studio and I want to run it but I am getting the following errors :

Build RubikaStore : failed
Download info
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
:app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:checkDebugAarMetadata
:app:processDebugMainManifest
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
:app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
:app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
:app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Gradle Sync issues


I did the following but it didn't solve the problem:

Sync Project With Gradle Files
Clean Project / Rebuild Project
In File > Project Structure :
Changed Compile SDK Version from 31 to 34
Changed Build Tools Version from 31 to 35
Changed Target SDK Version form 31 to 34
In AGP Upgrade Assistant :
Upgraded Android Gradle Plugin from 7.0.2 to 8.3.1


The problem is the used library net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout. The repositories where is was uploaded doesn't exist anymore or don't allow access.

I replaced implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2' with implementation 'com.github.cachapa:ExpandableLayout:2.9.2' in build.gradle (Module:app) and my problem resolved.
Thanks to @robert .
